# How to use pg_dump / pg_dumpall with postgres DB?

Tags: postgresql, unix, ubuntu, file-permissions, dump

I am uncertain if its the permissions issue or something I am doing wrong and any help will be greatly appreciated.
I have a dedicated Ubuntu server with Postgres DB installed on it. I want to backup the databases, but when I use pg_dump I get permission denied. Can some one help me out?
Here are a few details about my set up.

On postgres: I have the following databases.

```
postgres, 
template0, 
template1, 
mydb, 
mydb1
```

I have 2 PostgreSQL users

```
postgres, 
mydb (There are no postgresql groups defined yet)
```

All the other settings for postgres are default values.

On my ubuntu itself, I have 2 users.

```
user1,
mydb
```

I logged into the box as root/user1 using SSH, issued the following commands,

```
$ pg_dumpall > a.sql
```

I get, -bash: a.sql: Permission denied
Same goes with pg_dump command.

I know I am missing something here. Can some one guide me to properly issue this command?
TIA.

Comment: This is really an admin issue, not about programming. Voting to move to serverfault.com.

Answer (score 3):

> I get, -bash: a.sql: Permission denied
>   Same goes with pg_dump command.

This looks more like a file permission issue. Does the OS user have the right to write the dump file? Check file/directory permissions.

Answer (score 2):

When you run the command

```
pg_dumpall > a.sql
```

then your shell will attempt to create the file `a.sql` in the *current directory*. If you (as "user1") do not have permission to create files in the current directory, then first use the `cd` command to change to a directory where you do have permission. You can use the `pwd` command to see what the current directory actually is.